# How to add social login for Jhipster Gateway

Tags: jhipster

Have generated **UAA** + **Gateway**. I want to add social login, please someone help me to perform this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create monolithic application with social login ,then copy java files to uaa and frontend files to gateway

In gateway copy app/account/social ,app/shared/social folders and add modules and component to index.ts ,account-module.ts shared-modules.ts files

In uaa 
1-add spring social dependencies 
2-social configuration to yml files 
3-copy all social java file to uaa packages

Answer (score 1):

See this page on the jhipster website :

https://jhipster.github.io/tips/012_tip_add_new_spring_social_connector.html

Comment: No you didn't get my question. While generating **UAA** and **Gateway**, there is no option to add social login.